# Verified property type exists but still getting error?

Tags: javascript, properties, undefined

I am getting a

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

on the below code. Specifically, the error is regarding the `newStr[i].length` command. As you can see (commented out) I tested and can confirm that `newStr[1]` exists:

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var expression = /\w+/g;
  var newStr = str.match(expression);
  // return newStr[1].length;
  var longestWord = "";
  for (var i = 1; i < (newStr.length + 1); i++) {
    if (newStr[i].length > newStr[i - 1].length) {
      longestWord = newStr[i];
    } else {
      longestWord = longestWord;
    }
  }
  return longestWord;
}
console.log(findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use reduce instead? `newStr.reduce((a,b) => ((a.length > b.length) ? a : b))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is off-by-one. Also the output is not yet correct (outputs 'lazy'). You need to compare to `longestWord` instead of the previous word.

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var expression = /\w+/g;
  var newStr = str.match(expression);
  // return newStr[1].length;
  var longestWord = "";
  for (var i = 1; i < newStr.length; i++) { // fixed off-by-one
    if (newStr[i].length > longestWord.length) { // compare to longestWord
      longestWord = newStr[i];
    } else {
      longestWord = longestWord;
    }
  }
  return longestWord;
}
console.log(findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Gives `"jumped"`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! I really appreciate it, how do I mark this as solved?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 1; i < (newStr.length + 1); i++) {
```

newStr.length will be e. g. 4, then i will run up to 4, but newStr[4] does not exist. So it also hasnt a length.

You may do the whole stuff a bit shorter:

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  return str.split(" ").reduce((longest,curr)=>curr.length>longest.length?curr:longest,"");
}
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, the plus 1 needs to be removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you're indexing. Doing `i < newStr.length + 1` is the same as doing `i <= newStr.length`. Since everything is 0 indexed, you're attempting to access something at `newStr[newStr.length]` but the last possible element is at `newStr[newStr.length - 1]`.

Here's your code with correct indexing:

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var expression = /\w+/g;
  var newStr = str.match(expression);
  var longestWord = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++) {
    if (newStr[i].length > newStr[i - 1].length) {
      longestWord = newStr[i];
    } else {
      longestWord = longestWord;
    }
  }
  return longestWord;
}
console.log(findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

However, your logic is also flawed. If you want to find the longest word, you don't want to compare each word against the previous one. You want to compare the longest word you've found so far against each word you found.

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var expression = /\w+/g;
  var newStr = str.match(expression);
  var longestWord = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++) {
    /***********************************/
    if (newStr[i].length > longestWord.length) {
      longestWord = newStr[i];
    }
    /***********************************/
  }
  return longestWord;
}
console.log(findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This makes perfect sense, I didn't even consider that I needed to be comparing about the 'current' longestWord

Comment: @nuckingfut5 No worries. Glad I could help!